# Android project with Java libraries

Tags: android, eclipse, ant

I have an Android project which use a Java library which is being simultaneously developed.
My goal is to create a build.xml such that:

- When doing Clean it will do a Clean of Android project and of Java library.
- When doing Build All on Android project it will build Java library, creating a .jar, then copies the .jar into Android project libs folder and then builds the Android project.
- After editing the Java library and after cleaning rebuilding it, the Android project sees new methods of the Java library.

What I've done is not working correctly, although sometimes it does. I created a Java project containing library classes. There I created an Ant .xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="myJavaLib.makejar" default="makejar" basedir=".">
  <target name="clean">
      <delete dir="build"/>
  </target>
  <target name ="makejar" description="Creates a jar for the myJavaLib project">
    <jar jarfile="build/myJavaLib.jar" includes="**/*.class" basedir="bin/"/>
  </target>
</project>
```

I created a new Ant Builder and I associated this xml to it. The Ant Builder is after the default Java builder. Clean should delete build directory but actually doesn't work properly: when I do Clean nothing happens, then when I do Build, Clean is performed, then, after modifing a file and doing Build again, Build is performed.

In my Android Project, I created the following Ant .xml and I added a new Ant Builder and I put it before all other default Java and Android builders:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="myAndroid.makejar" default="makejar" basedir=".">
  <target name="clean">
      <delete dir="build"/>
  </target>
  <target name ="makejar" description="Creates a jar for the myAndroid project">
    <copy file="../myJavaLib/build/myJavaLib.jar" todir="./libs"/>
    <jar jarfile="build/myAndroid.jar" includes="**/*.class" basedir="bin/"/>
  </target>
</project>
```

I set the Android project to depend on the Java project into Java Build Path. I added an external JAR located in ./libs folder. (this is another problem: if the .jar is not yet been created I cannot add the external JAR).

What is the correct way of doing that?